# What is the Component Object Model (COM)? Is it language-dependent?

Tags: .net, com

I'm new to COM, and I don't know what it is or why it exists.

Is this a programming methodology like OOP? Do programming languages have to support it? (with some special keywords or something)

When I asked my professor about it, he said:

> COM is a binary-stable way to do OOP. We need to know binary-layout (something..something..)

I've no idea what it means. Some people say it is used for code reuse. OOP does a good job at that already, so then why did this COM evolve in the first place?

What is it with C++ and COM? Wherever I see COM, it's is always described with abstract C++ examples. Is it only for C++?

Can any one show me a case or exmaple so that I can understand the need for COM? What are the requirements for learning this, so I can write my own components?

Comment: "what are the requirements for learning this to write my own components?"  One key consideration: do you need to use COM for these components?  COM nowadays is basically legacy: you need it for environments that are already COM-based like Windows Explorer, but for most situations you would be more likely to use .NET, with DCOM replaced by messaging (e.g. WCF).  Unless you've got a specific use case that requires COM (or you're just generally interested in component architectures), it's probably not a great technology to be learning right now.

Comment: I think the reason you see so many C++ examples is the in-memory layout of a COM object is exactly the same as a C++ class with virtual functions.  There may be some minor differences that I don't remember, but C++ can use COM objects directly, as least most of the time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

COM at its core is a way of providing a data-passing contract which is independent of any specific language. It is provably not language dependent, as there are many languages which support COM (there are C++, C, .NET, and Java implementations)

In practice it is useful for a couple of different examples:

1. Communication between different languages: Because COM is language independent, it is possible to use COM to pass data between components in different languages. For instance you can use COM to talk between C++, Java, and .NET code.
2. Threading Semantics: COM allows you to define threading semantics for a particular component to ensure it is created in the appropriate thread context no matter where it is used.
3. General componentization.

Comment: >>"there are many languages which support COM "
So, a language must support it? like a language must support OOP? If so, why is it that I never heard of "Component Oriented Language like Object Oriented Language"?

Comment: @claws, It's actually possible to implement a COM layer in a language without any language specific support.  Essentially writing a COM serializer and message passer as an API.  I *think* that's how Java's implementation works but it's been a LONG time since I dealt with that.

Comment: COM absolutely does NOT require language support.  From the beginning it has been possible to create and use COM objects in plain ol' C.  No language support, just a bunch of macros.  The original C++ implementations of COM were also macro-based, with no language changes; even today I think the core of COM is still implemented via macros rather than language changes (there are helper types like _com_ptr_t, but these are helpers, not core).

Comment: I think you and Jared are thinking about different things when you hear "support". You seem to be thinking about support by constructs in the language's grammar, but I believe Jared just meant support as in "there's an API for it".

Answer (score 6):

COM was first created as a mechanism to allow Microsoft Office applications to communicate with one another, then, in its second iteration it was modified and extended to become a specification for how binary code components could--if they were constructed according to the specification-- communicate with each other, and share data, no matter what language or OS they were built upon (as long as the binary file (the compiled .dll or .exe) conformed to the COM specification).

The purpose was to allow "binary reuse" which means that a code component could be reused by multiple client code components, that the original code component knew nothing about, and which were not even in existence when the component was originally compiled. To quote from one of the original architects of COM, Don Box:

> [...] The design paradigm of COM was that component contracts are expressed as type definitions. This was a step forward from the world COM replaced, in which contracts were expressed only as simple functional entry points.In this respect, COM was a major advance because it brought the dynamic loading of code and the type system together in a fairly consistent manner.

Answer (score 4):

After thinking a while, I suppose the best way to put it for you to grasp the idea would be:

COM is a way to extend Windows API and publish other custom libraries in the system, so that you can discover and work with those new APIs in the same fashion without a need to recompile your application.

COM objects are *registered* in the system (by adding some hooks into the Windows registry). After that is done, your application can query in run-time existence of those expected libraries, and based on their availability to decide how to proceed further (instead of crashing when a statically linked library not found).

This mechanism is supposed to be language-independent, so any application written in any language should be capable of calling those interfaces and invoking operation of those libraries. In practice, however, some languages do not support some COM types so they get limited COM abilities.

Answering your question in comments:

To use COM no need to install anything. Everything is already there, in the form of WinAPI functions, which you can simply call in your application. DllGetClassObject and CoGetClassObject are used to instantiate COM objects. CoRegisterClassObject is used to register COM objects contained in your libraries in the system.

In order to enable uniform creation and interaction with COM objects, their creation has been entrusted to class factories, these are sort of helper objects. You call CoGetClassObject and ask it to let you talk to the class factory of the object you need. Given the interface to that class library, you ask it to instantiate the object you need. Then you can manipulate the object through interfaces it exposes.

Have a look at this brief overview on the Wikipedia: [Component Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model)

Comment: I see.. COM is for MS Windows. JavaBeans, CORBA are alternatives for COM on other Operating Systems. Right? Do I need to install any software to use COM alternative on other OSes?

Exactly which component of MSWindows will be managing these components?

Comment: COM can actually be used in the cross-platform environment, it's just its types need to be understood by all clients which is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

[Component Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) is a standard defined by Microsoft, for a language-independent binary object interface, i.e. it enables different OO languages to pass around objects and call methods on them.

Comment: The language need not be OO.  It's possible, albeit really really weird, to use non-OO languages like C to communicate with COM components.