# Need help understanding why I should use COM

Tags: com

I am having a tough time figuring out when I should use COM. I have done some reading but I simply cannot find a solid use-case for using it...I have browsed the internet trying to figure out **when** and **why** I should use it but the concept is simply too abstract and I don't understand it.

I get how using COM is interesting when it comes to writing code which can be consumed from various programming languages that support COM ([What is the Component Object Model (COM)? Is it language-dependent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645838/what-is-the-component-object-model-com-is-it-language-dependent)). But I would love to get a few solid examples of when COM was used and why it couldn't have been done realisticaly in another way.

Could someone list a few solid / real-world examples where using COM makes more sense that writing a DLL
which exports functionality through traditional functions if you put aside the multi-language aspect of COM ?

I know for instance that COM is used heavily in development which gravitates around Microsoft Office products...Why is this ?

Comment: Discoverability.

Comment: Re: Microsoft Office products. I think COM is used there mostly for the multi-language aspect (the part you wish to put aside). Microsoft Office products also heavily use Visual Basic (specifically, its dialect known as Visual Basic for Applications, or VBA) for scripting, and so need a mechanism for developers to write components that can be consumed from VBA.

Comment: In a sense, COM is merely a convenient way to export functionality through "traditional functions". A COM interface is little more than a table of pointers to functions. And it's bootstrapped by "traditional" exported functions like `DllGetClassObject`. You can even write COM components in C, setting up vtables manually with no help from the compiler; it's as "traditional functions" as it gets.

Comment: If you compare it with dllexports, COM allows you to build rich object-oriented hierarchies/domains using binary components (not source). The fact interface are carved in stone once published allows versioning (change binary inplace without changing callers). Associated with metadata/runtimeinfo tooling (tlb, winmd, etc.), it's much easier to use than exports/imports. Many Windows API are based on COM (DirectX and associated techs use the simplest form of COM - vtables). The new WinRT API is all based on COM too.

Comment: "if you put aside the multi-language aspect...".  No, that's what it is all about.  Microsoft uses C++ to develop its apps and libraries, but want to make them available to any language that a dev prefers.  That's a problem, C++ does not have a [*binary standard*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29302/c-lack-of-standardization-at-the-binary-level).  You really need one when you mix languages, COM provides it.